# keeping track of injected variables when using string interpolation in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, string-interpolation

I'm looking for a way to keep track of variables used when doing a string interpolation without parsing the string. For example, if I have a string:

```kotlin
val expStr = "${var1} some other useless text ${var2}"
```

I want to be able to identify the **order** of the variables used, again without parsing the string. In this case [var1, var2] would be an expected output. So far I've thought of defining a class where I pass it all of the variables. Then reference said variables through the class function `grab`.

```kotlin
val wrapper = ContainerClass(var1, var2)
val expStr = "${wrapper.grab(var1)} some other useless text ${wrapper.grab(var2)}"
```

inside `ContainerClass` is a array, each time a variable is referenced it is added to the array and outputted through `getReferenceCalls`

```kotlin
val whatIWant = wrapper.getReferenceCalls() // [var1, var2]
```

This works great until I introduce the injection of strings into strings.

```kotlin
val wrapper = ContainerClass(var1, var2, var3)
val snippet = "${wrapper.grab(var1)} some other useless text ${wrapper.grab(var2)}"
val expStr = "${wrapper.grab(var3)} ${snippet}"

val notWhatIWant = wrapper.getReferenceCalls() // [var1, var2, var3]
```

Here, I want to identify the order of the injected variables in the final expStr ie. [var3, var1, var2]. My question is, is this possible without parsing expStr? I did also think of a not so elegant solution of allowing my class to define any given "snippet" and the class identifies the variables referenced in the snippet. This works but becomes convoluted fast. What I really need is an eligant solution...if it exists.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place? You are the one who providing the input, you know everything about the input before the program even run. It makes no sense you want to get back the information about the input from the output. You have those information in the first place in order to produce the output.

Comment: Anyway, to give you some idea, each string should only be associated with one and only one `ContainerClass`, if a string use reference to another string, its `ContainerClass` should also reference to the corresponding `ContainerClass` of the referenced string.

Comment: Actually, the "string" is totally unrelated. Taking the strings out of the equation, you simply need to build a tree of variables, every subtree represent a string.

Comment: @RickyMo I am providing a pretty slimmed-down version of what I really want to accomplish. I am essentially building a very complex string and there are many snippets, loops, and if statements all feeding into a final string. The end result is that I don't know the order in which all the variables are referenced by the time the final string is constructed.

Comment: @RickyMo Your idea to reference each string in a `ContainerClass` is pretty similar to what I was getting at towards the end of the post. Though it may be cleaner than what I was doing. I may try this and see if it works better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented a "ContainerClass" to achieve your goal. I uses `String.format` instead of string templates so that I don't need prior information of the input.

```
class StringNode(private val format: String, vararg args : Any) {
    private val argv = args

    override fun toString() : String = String.format(format,*argv)

    fun getFlatArgs() : List<Any> = argv.flatMap {
        if(it is StringNode){
            it.getFlatArgs()
        } else{
            listOf(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
fun main(){
        val sn1 = StringNode("1:%s 2:%s 3:%s","abc",123,"def")
        println(sn1)
        println(sn1.getFlatArgs())

        val sn2 = StringNode("foo:%s bar:%s","foo",sn1);
        println(sn2)
        println(sn2.getFlatArgs())

        val sn3 = StringNode("sn1:%s, sn2:%s",sn1,sn2);
        println(sn3)
        println(sn3.getFlatArgs())
}
```

Output:

```
1:abc 2:123 3:def
[abc, 123, def]
foo:foo bar:1:abc 2:123 3:def
[foo, abc, 123, def]
sn1:1:abc 2:123 3:def, sn2:foo:foo bar:1:abc 2:123 3:def
[abc, 123, def, foo, abc, 123, def]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val var1 = "abc"
val var2 = "def"

val list = mutableListOf<String>()

val expStr = "${var1.also { list.add(it) }} some other useless text ${var2.also { list.add(it) }}"

println(expStr)   // Output: "abc some other useless text def"
println(list)     // Output: [abc, def]
```

Or:

```
val var1 = "abc"
val var2 = "def"

val list = mutableListOf<String>()
fun String.addTo(list: MutableList<String>) = this.also { list.add(it) }

val expStr = "${var1.addTo(list)} some other useless text ${var2.addTo(list)}"

println(expStr)   // Output: "abc some other useless text def"
println(list)     // Output: [abc, def]
```